# Kafka MirrorMaker consumer offset preservation ?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does it make sense to replicate the the __consumer_offsets topic using the MirrorMaker for DC failover?

I understand the essence of keeping the topic configuration (particularly # of partitions) same on both source and destination DCs.

But is this the only nuance about replicating the consumer offsets? I am sure there would be more, but I am not able to understand the bigger picture why replicating the consumer offsets across DC using MirrorMaker is deemed as daunting task ?